# OnClick Listener not working for buttons which exists in a linearlayout for which the alignParentBottom is true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I am having an activity and want to create a like button at the end of the layout, So I created a layout file and in a `LinearLayout` I have set it's `layout_alignParentBottom` property to true and created button for Likes in it. Now I am including this layout file in some other layout file but when I am applying `onClickListener` to the button, it does nothing.

When I remove this `layout_alignParentBottom` from the `LinearLayout` properties, then `OnclickListener` start working.

Can you please help me here to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you post the codes of both layout please..

Comment: I have resolved this issue, the issue was coming because of the layout_height set to match_parent.

Comment: I am having one more problem. I am having one TextView and want to set only an icon in this textview, then I want to make that icon of the Textview clickable. How can I achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

Some other widget might be coming in its way. if there is something above that button, it wont take clickListener.

For Ex. if there is a list in that layout too,

```
<Button
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/viewSpace1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight_small"
    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
    style="@style/ButtonLogin"
    android:text="Next" />

<ListView 
    android:layout_above="@id/btnShare"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutHeader"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/viewSpace3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

so your share button stays safe for clickability.
I have kept the list above `btnShare`. Just for my safety if it overlaps the button.If there is still problem, post your code so exact problem can be pin pointed.

Comment: Hii, I am having viewpager and it's having 3 tabs. All the 3 tabs are having their own Fragments. First time I have setup the title of the tabs using getPageTitle function of FragmentPagerAdapter. But now when I click on any tab some work I am doing there and need to change the title of the tab inside it's fragment. 

For Ex: I am having one Tab that's showing title Photos (2), here 2 is the photoCount, now when I upload more photos under this tab, I need to set the title to photos (Count). 

How can I achieve this, please help me here, your help is too much appreciated.